# How does reputation reversal in special cases work?

Tags: discussion, reputation

Recently I lost a few reputation due to "User Deleted", which made me wonder about reputation reversal:

1. If someone answered my question and I get 2 rep by accepting it, then the answerer deleted his profile, will I lose 2?
2. If I am new to a community with only 1 rep (new user). I get a down vote without losing 2 **before** getting another up vote. Will I have 9 rep or 11 rep?
3. If I have 11 rep from Question 2, then the down vote gets reverted, will I gain an extra 2 or will it remain the same?
4. Even worse, if I am new with 1 rep. I get a up vote **then** a down vote and I have 9. The up vote gets retracted **before** the down retracts. Do I have 1 or 3?

Comment: You may want to split these into different questions

Comment: @Steve I don't think that's necessary. At least the questions 2-4 are tightly related.

Comment: Most of this can be answered at [How does “Reputation” work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7237/21960)

Answer (score 3):

> 1. If someone answered my question and I get 2 rep by accepting it, then the answerer deleted his profile, will I lose 2?

Depends:

If the answer will remain as *community wiki*, you'll not lose any rep gained by accepting.

If the user was destroyed with all of their posts, you'll lose that rep.

> 2. If I am new to a community with only 1 rep (new user). I get a down vote without losing 2 **before** getting another up vote. Will I have
>      9 rep or 11 rep?

Downvotes applied before upvotes for a user at rep 1 won't count (but are visible). If their are upvotes already, a downvote will reduce the rep gained before.

So in your case for an upvoted answer, you'll end up with 11.

> 3. If I have 11 rep from Question 2, then the down vote gets reverted, will I gain an extra 2 or will it remain the same?

It will just remain the same, there never was any rep taken away.

> 4. Even worse, if I am new with 1 rep. I get a up vote **then** a down vote and I have 9. The up vote gets retracted **before** the down
>      retracts. Do I have 1 or 3?

See above. No extra rep there.